# Loop program output

Tags: c, loops

I got curious and experimented a little on looping and I kind of confused myself here.

Question 1:
Why does this code output 012345678910 instead of 00000000000111111111112222222222233333333333444444444445555555555566666666666777
7777777788888888888999999999991010101010101010101010 ?

```
for(a=0;a<=10;a++){
    for(a=0;a<=10;a++){
        printf("%d", a);
    }
}
```

Question 2: For the code shown below, does taking out the first statement mean that it would start on 0? If yes, then why does it output 12345678910 instead of 01234567891001234567891001234567891001234567891001234567891001234567891001234567
8910012345678910012345678910012345678910012345678910 ?

```
for(a=0;a<=10;a++){
    for(;b<=10;b++){
        printf("%d", b);
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you initialize `b` then?

Comment: You are iterating on the same variable a within the 2 loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Because when `a` reaches 10 in the inner loop, the outer loop also exits, so you only see

   ```
   012345678910
   ```
2. Because after the 1st time the outer loop is executed, `b` is already 11 and the inner loop is no longer executed.

   For your desired output, you should reset `b` to zero every time the outer loop is executed

   ```
   for (...) {
       for (b = 0; ... ; ...) {...}
       //   ^~~~~ This is what you should do
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, you are not getting the answer because you use same counter variable in inner loop:

Modify it to use different variable:

```
for(int a=0;a<=10;a++){
    for(int b=0;b<=10;b++){
        printf("%d", a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have same counter for outer and inner loop which is in this case incorrect. Use counter `a` and `b` then loop should work.
2. In inner loop `b` stays 11 after first iteration, if you want to achieve your expected result add `b = 0` in your inner loop